# How to get back Google's search tools

Tags: google-search

Google is seemingly opting out "search tools" features in its search results:

[image]

A bunch of useful tools was in this menu before. For example, the "visited pages" and "reading level" filters. Now they're gone.

Is there a way to access these old features from parameters in URL or any other way?

Comment: Google constantly adds (and removes) ancillary features like that. It's likely that they weren't used much and/or lost in a redesign. It's likely that there will be no way to get them back.

Comment: @AlE. I hoped Google left these features but removed them from the menu. This is why I'm asking for a sample URL of, at least, "Visited pages".

Comment: I know. I hope so, too. Unfortunately I don't know what they are or if they're available. I do know that Google has broken my heart a couple of times; I was just letting you know the same could be true here.

Comment: [Search Engine Land](http://searchengineland.com/google-drops-another-search-filter-reading-level-220581) reported that reading level is dropped. Even you have that url parameter, the result page would show "The search option you have selected is currently unavailable." FYI: `&tbs=rl:1`

Comment: "Visited pages" are automatically included in the search if you are logged in and have the "Search history" enabled.

Answer (score 0):

For looking through your visited pages, I couldn't find any feature other than some chrome extensions that showed the most visited pages on google.

Example of some plugins that do this: [Most Visited](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/most-visited/obbnkbhoknnlndofpoikddaompgmiioc?hl=en), [Recent History](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/recent-history/fbmkfdfomhhlonpbnpiibloacemdhjjm?hl=en)...

You can also try looking at the google archives to see previous versions of google and copy the code or something,

Other than that for visited pages, you can easily search through the closed tabs/history page,

[image]

But not all visited pages, just most visited and history...

Regarding the reading level feature, you can see the archive file [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20141010035324/http://www.google.com/advanced_search?hl=en), but there are also some chrome exertions that have some aspects of that feature. Depending on why you wanted it there are alternatives.

That's all I know about those features, hopefully it could help a little.

Comment: It appears the advanced search page (google.com/advanced_search) has the same functionality regardless of the JavaScript option. Without JavaScript, this page is the sole item under "Search tools". So overall Google offers more search customization with JavaScript enabled.

Comment: I changed the answer more suited to the features rather than the old google layout.

Answer (score -2):

I haven't figured out how to get the reading level, but you can go to Advanced Search, scroll to the bottom, and click on "Search pages you've visited."

Comment: It redirects to a help page linked to a google.com/history, which is unlike the filter.